# Identifying javascript functions which effect selected html elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out which javascript functions are changing specified html elements. I have a whole bunch of javascript functions and all that I have deduced is that with javascript disabled the elements style differently.

Be there a firefox plugin of sorts?

Comment: The only way I can think of is going through the JavaScript code manually and try to identify the effects

Comment: not sure if this help, but in chrome if i inspect an element i can see if it's style come from  js, html itself or css file! hope this help

Comment: cheers @aSeptik thats gotta be worth a try. It turns out I did manually sort through and found where it was, but this certainly would have helped.

Answer (score 0):

There might be tools that does it... One possible way is to commenting out the several lines in various function that you suspect that does it.  You can use binary search to find it: 4 lines commented out.  And if that fixes the problem you know it is one of these 4 lines, then now you can commented out only 2 of those lines, etc.  Then you can find the line that does it in O(log n) time.